# How to repair Grub with Live CD of Different Version of Ubuntu

Tags: grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (upgraded from 11.10) 32-bit and Windows-7 64-bit simultaneously in my computer. I want to install windows-8 but I haven't any backup of Ubuntu 12.04 to retrieve grub after installing windows. So, my question is :-

**Is it possible to repair grub with different version of Ubuntu Live CD? If possible then how could I do that and how risky that process?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the questions are:

Is it possible to repair grub with different version of Ubuntu Live CD?

If possible then how could I do that and how risky that process?

The answers are:

Yes, it is possible and safe. It does not involve any risk to repair the Grub.

Should just do it through chroot:

Insert the Ubuntu LiveCD into the CD/DVD drive and reboot the computer. The machine boots from the LiveCD.

Click the “Try Ubuntu Without Installing” icon from the LiveCD “Start” menu. Ubuntu boots from the LiveCD.

Click “Applications” from the top taskbar in the Ubuntu desktop, and then click “Accessories.”

Click the “Terminal” option. The Ubuntu command-line terminal opens.

Type the following command at the prompt and press the “Enter” key. Replace “sdax” with the name of your “root” partition linux 8300.

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
mount /dev/sdax /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
umount /mnt
reboot
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I've found these instructions here very useful. I think one thing is incorrect though. In the first grub-install line, the --root-directory doesn't seem to make sense... that "/mnt" is now just / in the chroot, so I think that parameter should just be omitted.

Comment: I'd also add that on many systems these days, the commands would be grub2-mkconfig and grub2-install. And also that you may need to mount your EFI partition to /mnt/boot/efi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but dangerous and silly given the availability of Ubuntu Install CDs.

[This should give you the current downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and [Here is a list of mirrors that have all versions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)(bottom of page).

[This site also has](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) several versions.

If you insist on using an old version (again very risky) give [this site](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) a try. Basically you mount your partition, change to it, then run grub from your "current" system. This should minimize problems, but is still risky. As with any and all partition (boot loader) edits **backup your data** ASAP.

Comment: If your on Ubuntu 12.04 then you want the 12.04 install cd, NOT the 11.10. Grub was updated when you installed 12.04.

Comment: I had install lots of package and due to internet problem I could neither download iso file of 12.04 nor reinstall ubuntu...

Comment: then download the CD from your windows 8 setup, or a friends computer. Installing an older version of GRUB will work, but if the config file syntax has changed your going to end up with a non-booting system. (also there could be stage2 issues).

Comment: If you mean you have no internet at all, then your going to have to ask a friend for help.

Comment: see my updated question... and thanks for your idea for downloading...

Comment: updated answer, follow the steps, it should work, and be slightly less risky then using just the live CD version of GRUB.

Comment: I don't see how this is dangerous at all. Using `grub-install` to re-install GRUB, even from an older version, will simply install an older version of GRUB in the boot partition, rescan and recreate the GRUB configuration and modify the boot sector accordingly. `grub-install` even checks for errors before proceeding. Once GRUB is installed, you can reboot and force a reinstall of the newest version. I installed GRUB for my Ubuntu install with an old Debian CD once, and never had any problems.

Comment: There are several "versions" of grub, and at times they need matching kernel/configs. For example grub-efi and grub-pc are not interchangeable on my MBP. Using efi will result in a broken system. However if I configured my system for efi, using pc would break everything. Older versions from live cds may guess (and they do even between 12.04 and 12.10) and install the wrong grub. That said the method I mentioned uses the version on the system, so it should work fine. Of course any boot modification is dangerous, and could result in a broken system.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I don't have to recover Grub on installing Window 8 through non bootable pen drive (on clicking setup.exe file). And no problem were arise.