# Accidentally borked system by pressing Ctrl + C during sudo apt upgrade. How do I fix it?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates, crash

Was attempting to run  `sudo apt upgrade`and hit Ctrl c when it gave me a prompt that I could not figure out how to get out of.

Tried to rerun `sudo apt upgrade`. Got a message about some kind of lock process being occupied. Foolishly, tried to restart it. This happens after selecting Ubuntu to start. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzxNO.jpg
Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Stopping a package upgrade can do that, easily. Rebooting while the process is still going, the reason for the locked process, also a very bad idea. So, never do that. Now, I think, the fastest solution is reinstall Ubuntu but perhaps other people may have other ideas.

Comment: I would boot a 'live' medium (eg. Ubuntu install media) and `fsck` your system. I would try and get it so I could login to runlevel 1 (terminal only running) and then look at what the last package that was being installed in your logs (taking note of it!). I would then  `sudo apt upgrade` and hope it would continue (it may want dpkg-reconfigure if so do it).  When completed i'd possibly `install --reinstall` the aborted package noted earlier.  I'd evaluate this by what I saw in messages as steps run.  (*a re-install something-else no-format can always be done later if it gets messy*)

Comment: @guiverc Can you post a more detailed instruction on that as an answer? That should help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would boot a 'live' medium (eg. your Ubuntu install media) and `fsck` your system.  `fsck` is a file-system-check command that will check for, then fix any errors in your file-system.  (depending on what fs I'm using, I sometimes use xfs_check but I'm betting `fsck` will be right for you).

My first purpose would be to hopefully get so I can login to recovery or runlevel 1 (text terminal only and not use gui).

I would login (text term or runlevel 1) and look for the last package that was being installed in your logs (I'd `stat /var/log/apt/history.log` hoping it'd have a time/date stamp that matches your ^C then `view` it's contents), taking note of the last installed package (even last 2-3).

I would then `sudo apt upgrade` and hope it would continue.  If it complains and wants me to run any `dpkg-reconfigure` commands, I'd do what it wants and repeat the `sudo apt upgrade` until all upgrades were complete (0 remain). Myself I'd probably `sudo apt dist-upgrade` as well.

When completed i'd possibly `sudo apt install --reinstall` the aborted package (one being installed when you ^C that was hopefully found & noted earlier).

Of course I'd evaluate this by what I saw in messages as steps run. At this stage it would include a reboot & use of system normally at first to test how it goes.

If I wasn't completely happy with the results, or unsure about anything; I'd consider `install --reinstall` those packages, or just go to a whole Ubuntu re-install.

My re-install choice would be using "*Something else*" selecting my partitions and ensuring I had 'no-format' which can be quicker.  This option takes note of added packages, erases system directories, then installs, adds back your added software [packages] without touching your user directories or files. I want to trust my systems, so this would be my fall-back if I wasn't happy with any step.

Comment: this answer is rather hurried; sorry I'm busy currently.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will meet up with one of my techie friends who is usually helpful with this kind of stuff later this week. This answer should let us try some stuff for a fix  Even that bit about reinstall is super helpful, might even be easier to just take that reinstall option in particular.

Comment: @guiverc You may want to point out, that you can `chroot` into the installed system and update/fix from there if booting does not work.

Comment: @KevInski is right, but there are loads of situations I haven't covered, these maybe helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/915617/after-repairing-deleted-kernel-why-would-grub-still-not-boot-into-linux & https://askubuntu.com/questions/234384/how-to-repair-grub-with-live-cd-of-different-version-of-ubuntu (*though I'm browsing commands more than headings/text so my reason for grabbing them may be missed*). I would watch messages (looking for problems or *things that don't look right* and adjust accordingly. or search askubuntu, ubuntuforums, or asking on irc etc

Comment: This was pretty helpful. We wound up taking some backups by connecting the disk to another pc with a SATA cable and then doing the final reinstall option you listed. Although this answer could be improved with screenshots of the steps for that option, great work for suggesting it - definitely saved my computer's bacon.