# Bootloader not found after completely removing windows and replacing with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I previously had dual booted Ubuntu alongside Windows, fastforward two years and i wished to remove Windows since i had messed around with the partitions and couldn't get it to boot anymore. I followed the official askubuntu guides to remove the windows partitions and extend my Linux partition to make it the sole OS. I also reinstalled GRUB immediately after but now when i boot up, i get the black screen of Bootloader not found. I can't see a boot flag either even though my partitioning table is MSDOS. Any help here as to how to get grub to work again?

```
fdisk -l
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x347864a3

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda4           2048 976771071 976769024 465.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5           4096  83890175  83886080    40G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       83892224  92280831   8388608     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       92282880 976771071 884488192 421.8G 83 Linux
```

[Here's an exact picture of what I'm faced with when i boot, to be clear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47sVj.jpg)

Thank you for any help!
[Pastebin link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jvk5nRzND7/)

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/234384/how-to-repair-grub-with-live-cd-of-different-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: @StephenDaddona I used a GParted Live CD to do the above

Comment: Did you do the grub-mkconfg and grub-install commands as well as the fdisk list command?  I only see the fdisk list command in your post.  I do see it in the Pastebin link.  If you did those commands as well, then I'm out of ideas for the moment.  I've always found that reinstalling grub fixed my boot problems.

Comment: Yes, i ran the grub-install commands and even tried to fix it through the boot-repair GUI(which is how i generated the pastebin link). If you see, i have nothing from 1-2048, which i think is what is causing the problem, but i don't know how to fix that lol

Comment: Oh, one more thought: did you do " update-grub " after you made any changes?

Comment: No i didn't run that since it wasn't mentioned in this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) I'll have to run it through my Live ubuntu install, won't that mean I'm updating the Live install's GRUB?

Comment: I also have nothing from 1-2048 on either of my hard drives.  Ubuntu is installed on the second hard drive in my system.  At one time, I had Debian on the first hard drive, but that has long since been removed.

Comment: I think you need to be root to do update-grub.   I need to log off for a few hours, but I wish you success and hope you get this resolved soon.

Comment: I will give it a try, good suggestion, i hope it works too. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The update-grub command is there, WAY down the document under the "Fixing a Broken System" section. It's one of many, "step 6" statements.  Easy to miss.   I know I would have missed it.  Ok, I'm outta here for now.  Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I Did the entire process of reinstalling via Chroot but to no avail :(

Comment: That exhausts everything I can think of.  I wonder if the drive has a bad boot sector.  I don't know how to check for that.

Comment: The boot partition should be marked as bootable - see the asterisk in this example: [   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048   732566645  2930258392   83  Linux
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)
]

Comment: Yes, i mentioned that i couldn't see the boot flag set on any partition which caused me to think something was wrong. I'll wait around for someone to provide a different solution or else i'll just wipe it completely and fresh install Manjaro ^.^

Comment: You have an UEFI system, but BIOS/MBR installs. Be sure to have UEFI set to boot in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode. And always boot live installer in BIOS mode and add Boot-Repair to it with ppa. Grub does not use boot flag, but some BIOS/UEFI need boot flag to work, so best to have one on some partition.

Comment: @oldfred 
Okay so I need to to boot the live cd in legacy/bios mode and then run grub-repair?

Answer (score 0):

[image: GParted - marking partition as bootable]The boot flag is not set on your boot partition.  I just noticed that in your fdisk listing.  Use gparted to mark that partition as bootable.  Then run update-grub again and see if that fixes it.

Comment: in gparted, select the partition, then click on "Partition" from the menu bar, then "Manage flags on <device>" then check "boot" and save those settings.

Comment: You might want to use dev/sda5 as your boot partition and then go through all the steps again to install grub.  Don't forget to do update-grub at the end, which will find your bootable partition and write your master boot record for you.

Comment: I tried this, the boot flag was set through gparted and i verified it through fdisk too. reinstalled grub through chroot but to no avail. I've updated the question with the error screen so maybe that can make it clearer the issue i have? Have a look mate

Comment: Please see @oldfred's comment in the question section.  I am almost completely ignorant regarding UEFI other than to know that it replaces BIOS. Oldfred mentioned that you have a UEFI system with BIOS/MBR installs.  I have no clue how he even determined that.  I'm going to plead ignorance on this and bow out.  Just on the chance that your live CD has a flawed grub, do you have a different live CD that you could try this from?

Comment: The boot-flag is not needed under Linux.

Comment: Yes, he seems to make a good point. I will pursue that further. I can always install ubuntu fresh on my usb, that's not an issue. Thank you for taking the time out to help me, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In [Explaining UEFI Firmware for Linux Users](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/legacy-bios-vs-uefi-bios) and [Understanding the Boot process — BIOS vs UEFI](https://linuxhint.com/understanding_boot_process_bios_uefi/) there are some good discussions about the differences between booting with a BIOS or Legacy mode, versus UEFI.

I think that a better understanding of the boot process will help your solution make sense. Unless your computer is 10 or more years old (like mine), I'm guessing you have UEFI, which is the updated firmware, but as [oldfred's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237875/bootloader-not-found-after-completely-removing-windows-and-replacing-with-ubuntu/1238010#comment2084865_1237875) has pointed out, Linux appears to be installed in legacy or BIOS mode.

The basic issue here which I noticed from your boot-repair is that your system is booting in EFI mode, this requires there to be an EFI system partition (or ESP) which would contain booting instructions.  What likely happened is that this partition was wiped when you were messing with `/` deleting Windows and now the system is not seeing a boot loader.

Comment: While expanding my Linux partitions, I deleted the Windows reserved partition, since it wasn't mentioned anywhere to keep it. I think that's caused this whole shitton of issues to crop up

Comment: Any luck in booting into your live USB Ubuntu in legacy mode, and then running boot-repair?

Comment: No, sorry no luck with that. It still wasn't able to detect a bootloader. I ended up reformatting my entire hard drive and then converting the table to GPT through the windows installer and then installing Manjaro as my primary OS.

Comment: Did you end up re-installing the dual boot setup, or just Manjaro?

Comment: I had to put windows first because i didn't see any option to quit the setup after formatting my hdd, then i put Manjaro by removing windows